# protoc decode error: Enum type has no value named

Tags: protocol-buffers

i'm trying to call this command: ./protoc --decode=InitialDataResponse --proto_path=protos InitialDataResponse.proto < Data.bin but i'm facing the error: Enum type "Protos.UnitTier" has no value named "TIER01"

Answer (score 0):

The binary encoded protobuf data *does not include* enum names. Enum values are encoded simply as integer values, and unexpected values are not a strict error (although how you access an unexpected enum value depends on whether you're using proto2 or proto3 conventions).

That sounds like an error in the .proto schema; - `InitialDataResponse.proto`. Most likely, an invalid default value declaration (`[default = ...]`): specifying an enum value that doesn't exist. So: search `InitialDataResponse.proto` for `TIER01` and fix that.

Without a valid .proto schema you can still do a *fair* job of deciphering encoded protobuf data, but it will be much easier to decode if you can use the schema. Right now: your .proto schema (not the data) is invalid.